# Google Chrome Remote Debugging - Loading Page

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been reading through Google Chrome Remote Debugging documentation (http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/remote-debugging.html), but I still don't understand how do I open a new web page in Google Chrome. I am using Python and after launching Google Chrome with --remote-debugging-port, I can only communicate with /json on the localhost (I am writing a custom debugger for internal testing).

I have tried to build a JSON object by reading this http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/protocol/page.html and send it to /json, but no results.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I found out how to send the commands - connecting through Web Sockets to the webSocketDebuggerUrl returned when doing a query to /json (you can use websocket for python) and then simply sending the parameters (json format) as defined.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can ask your further questions in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google/chrome-developer-tools if you like. (I just got your question about DevTools with help of Google Alert's rss feed);
2. you can sniff the messages between DevTools and Chrome (Open DevTools in detached mode, open DevTools for DevTools, open console in the second instance and write window.dumpInspectorProtocolMessages = 1)

Comment: Note: Instructions for setting up sniffing are located at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#sniffing-the%20protocol. BUT, those instructions don't mention the "window.dumpInspectorProtocolMessages = 1" step, so thank you very much for that.